# Pass value from a html form to another (redirected page) through node API

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I have the form IDForm.html and registration.html

if the user input the correct ID in **IDForm.html**  it's redirected to **registration.html**

the ID is the objectID of collection in mongodb

the check of ID on mongooseDB is done on nodejs API

```
const checkID = async (req, res ,next){
    var ID = "5e9cca24beabb96a4caedc35" 
    User.findById(ID, 
        (err) => {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            res.redirect('/api/users/'+ ID +'/register')        
        })
```

how can i redirect to registration page with this ID loaded in. so the user in the registration can update his collection on mongodb using this ID

the registration is a kind of updating an existing collection on mongodb

Comment: Are you receiving an error message? In what way is this not working as expected?

Comment: Are you using a templating engine of some sort?

Comment: Im not using a Templating engine, the index.html is loaded in the server.js  and then all other pages are redirected from the index and from one page to another, i don't know if this is the rright choice or should use res.sendfile for each page, or a templating engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the registration side, the route should be able to get the parameters from the request URL and pass it to the front end.

Let's say this is the registration route:

```
router.get('/registration,(req,res)=>{

//You will have the access to the URL parameters here
//Just an example
console.log(req.params.id)


//Pass the id to the front end if you are using a templating
// engines like express or ejs
res.render('template',{

id:req.params.id

});

//Or you can just send it out using
res.send(req.params.id)

//And handle it in the front end as you like


});
```